# Bind function blocking click function from working?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a few click functions in my code that aren't working since I added the .bind() function. I don't know if that's actually the problem, but I can't think of anything else it would be.

The way the code is supposed to work is:

- load data from xlsx file
- load content from a different html file
- runData()
- proceed as normal (click functions as needed)

Here's the JS:

```
oReq.onload = function(e)
{    
    // doing something... //
    $(document).trigger('complete');
}

jQuery(document).ready(function()
{
    $('#videoButton').click(function()
    {
        $('html, body').animate(
        {
            scrollTop: $("#video").offset().top - 225
        }, 1000);

    });

    // BACK TO TOP
    $('#toTop').click(function()
    {
        $('html, body').animate(
        {
            scrollTop: $("#about").offset().top
        }, 1000);

    });
});

$(document).bind('complete', function()
{        
    console.log(jobs); //global variable

    console.log(sponsors); //global variable

    setTimeout(function()
    {
    runData(jobs);
    }, 0); 

});
```

Comment: FYI, `bind` is deprecated, you should use `on` instead.

Comment: I can't think of any way that the `complete` event could interfere with the `click` events. Are you seeing any errors in the JavaScript console?

Comment: There are no errors on my console.

Comment: Can you try to move the `$(document).bind()` above the `oReq.onload` assignment?

Comment: not 'click'...change `$(document).bind(...` to `$(document).on(...`. (that won't matter though)

Comment: I never said it would fix anything.

Comment: You should also step through this code with a debugger. it might be a simple order of operation as I indicated above.

Comment: @RandyCasburn Why would the order matter? Event handlers run in the order that the events are triggered, the order that you added them doesn't matter (unless you have mutliple handlers for the same event).

Comment: I have debugged it, and the elements are all there in time to be clicked. But I can't move it before oReq.onload. It's on a separate file that affects multiple pages and runData is specific to one.

Comment: @Barmar - sure it matters if the event fires prior to the handler being in memory

Comment: Scripts are loaded synchronously. Events don't fire until the script finishes loading.

Comment: The element that I'm trying to click on was loaded from another html file. Does that make a difference?

Answer (score 0):

The .bind() was not the issue, it was because the button was added dynamically. I was able to fix it by changing

```
$('#videoButton').click(function()
```

to:

```
$(document).on('click', '#videoButton', function()
```